# Counting the expected number of strings with a given contiguous substring.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, computer-science, combinatorics-on-words

**Question:**

Let a random bit string $x$ of length $n$ be given.

What is the expected number of bit strings $w$ of length $2n$ that contain $x$ as a contiguous substring?

**What I know:**

For any bit string $x$ of length $n$, the total number of length $2n$ bit strings $w$ that contain $x$ as a contiguous substring is between $2^n$ and $(n+1) \cdot 2^n$.  The exact number may depend on the string $x$ that you pick.

**To the point:**

Is the expected number $\Theta(2^n)$, or $\Theta(n \cdot 2^n)$, or something in between?

Comment: @TravisJ Any upper bounds or lower bounds are helpful.  The best upper bound that I have is $(n+1) \cdot 2^n$.

Comment: There are $n+1$ choices for where the string $x$ can appear in $w$.  Then, there are only $n$ additional bits to fill in.

Comment: Also, there is some string $x$ where this upper bound appears to be tight.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake.  The $2^{n}(n+1)$ is the same bound I get.

Comment: You can subtract 1 for avoiding double counting of the string contains x twice.

Comment: I think the problem should be "total number of bit strings w of length 2n..."

Comment: @i707107 Should I say total or expected?  The total should be between $2^n$ and $(n+1)\cdot 2^n$.  And, the total will depend on the $x$ that we choose.  I want the expected total for a random $x$.  :)

Comment: I see, so you are considering for all possible x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expected number is $\Theta(n\, 2^n)$.  The OP observes that this is an upper bound, so we need to show it is a lower bound.

In one sentence, the proof is: $x$ probably doesn't overlap itself, so you can only fit $O(1)$ copies of $x$ into any one $2n$-long string, so the occurrences of $x$ as substrings must be distributed over lots of $2n$-long strings.

Here are more details; I'm going to ignore some ceilings and floors for simplicity.
Fix an $n$-long string $x$; let $s(x)$ denote the smallest "shift amount" $s$ such that $x$ "overlaps" with itself at a shift of $s$; that is, the $(n-s)$-prefix of $x$ agrees with the $(n-s)$-suffix of $x$.  (Set $s(x)=n$ if no such shift amount exists.)  Then a $2n$-long string can only contain $1+n/s(x)$ copies of $x$.

The total number of $n$-long strings $x$ with $s(x)\le k$ is at most $2^1+2^2+\cdots+2^{k}<2^{k+1}$.  So the probability that $s(x)<n/2$ is $O(2^{-n/2})$.  Thus, with probability at least $1-O(2^{-n/2})$, the maximum number of occurrences of $x$ in any $2n$-long string is at most $1+n/(n/2)=3$.

Finally, the total number of pairs $(w,i)$ such that $w$ is a $2n$-long string, in which $x$ occurs as a substring at position $i$, is $(n+1)2^n$.  The previous paragraph shows that these occurrences of $x$ as substrings are spread out: with probability at least $1-O(2^{-n/2})$, $x$ occurs in at least
$(n+1)2^n /3$ of the words $w$.  Hence the expectation, taken over $x$, of the number of words $w$ containing $x$, is at least 
$$(1-O(2^{-n/2}))(n+1)2^n /3= \Omega(n\, 2^n)$$
as required.

Comment: This is awesome!  Thank you very much Tad.  :)

Comment: Just to let you know, I was working on a state complexity problem in automata theory.  This combinatorial question turned out to be related.  Your answer helped us make a little bit of progress.  :)

Comment: But, really, it helped me better understand how to deal with counting problems that involve contiguous substrings.

Comment: My initial thought was to try to get an exact expression using the Goulden-Jackson cluster method, but it seems hard to compute the precise probabilities of various overlap structures. But you kindly only asked for a $\Theta$!

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the Goulden-Jackson cluster method.  It is arrestingly described by John Noonan and Doron Zeilberger as "replace the hard-to-count set of 'good guys' by the weighted count of the much larger set of pairs (arbitrary-guy, arbitrary-subset-of-his-sins), where the weight is (-1) to the power of the cardinality of the subset of his sins"; see http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimhtml/gj.html for the paper and software.